# Foundation responsive only to a certain width

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I´m using zurb foundation to create a responsive website. When i resize my window the grid changes to the mobile mode, it´s normal behavior. Is there any way that when i resize the window the website stays put and the browser only adds a scrollbar?
I still need the mobile version to exist, for mobiles only, and i have already try to use min-width to set the point where the scrollbar is added.

Does any one have any idea how to do this?

**EDITED**

I have the folowing media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

And in the html i have elements whith the folowing class:

```
small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css file change the media query to `max-device-width` to target devices only.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm using that in css, but the problem is in html i have this: "small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-3" witch i need for the devices. So when the window gets smaller it changes the layout.

Comment: Do you have a media type before `max-device-width`?

Comment: I edited my question with the full info on what i´m using. But if i understand correctly, you are saying that if i remove "(max-width: 480px)" it will do what i want and ignore this "small-block-grid-1" ??

Comment: try changing `only screen` to `only handheld` :)

Comment: I did what you suggested but no luck still changes the structure.